# get campaign stats to mailwizz api with node js

Tags: node.js, axios

I am using mailwizz in my node js app and I want to get campaign stats. They provide the api docs in php and ruby but not in node js. Is there any solution to get campaign stats by using axios?

I am trying to get campaign stas from mailwizz in node js.

https://github.com/MikelCalvo/node-mailwizz

In there api docs they are only providing create campaign api